# Select string which contains

Tags: java, mysql, regex

This is a very simplified version of what i'm working on but hopefully it will get my point across.

I have a mysql table which looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
  ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Val VARCHAR(50),
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
INSERT INTO Table1 (Val) SELECT "Reference.Int('ABCD')";
INSERT INTO Table1 (Val) SELECT "Reference.Str('EFG','ABC')";
INSERT INTO Table1 (Val) SELECT "Reference.Int('HIJ','EFG','ABC')";
```

The method i'm working on receives as parameter one of the values in the brackets, for example: "EFG". Is it possible for me to grab all the rows in the table which contain this value. I am aware that if i do something like:

```
SELECT * from Table1 where Val LIKE "%EFG%"
```

i can get the right values, my problem is that i need to be more specific because for example one of the values can look something like :

```
 Reference.Int('ABCD') + EFGX/200
```

or

```
EFG + anything else
```

Meaning that i need to somehow include this parts also: "Reference.Str()". I don't really care about anything else that is in the brackets, my only concern is to get the ones which contain the value of the parameter i receive.

I was wondering if this could be solved by using REGEXP, but my knowledge of this is weak at best.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why is `Val LIKE "%EFG%"` not sufficient?

Comment: @ruakh: Consider the following value "Reference.Int('EGFGASDSFSDGF')"

Comment: So would LIKE "%'EFG'%" be better?

Comment: I'm sorry, that example i gave was a bad one (about why 'LIKE %EFG%' is not enough, i will update it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp, but there's no need. Just include the quotes surrounding your values in the search term:

```
select ...
where val like '%\'EFG\'%'
```

Comment: thank you all for your answers and for being patient with a question that is probably very silly

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good fit for a SQL query. You're probably best off creating a second table that stores tokens found in strings, and a reference back to the parent record.

So you could do something like

```
select record_id from tokens where token_val = 'EFG';
```

and then

```
select * from records where record_id in (*results from pervious query)
```

Basically the idea is to do the hard work up front, ONCE per record, rather than trying to parse on the fly on every query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Val LIKE "Reference.Str(%'EFG'%"
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/437b9/1)**

Comment: This would work if there were only "Reference.Str" but there are a few more variants of this. Thank you for the answer nonetheless

Comment: @DanielV Sorry, my mistake. You must get common part. If all starts with `"Reference.` you can use this: `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Val LIKE "Reference.%(%'EFG'%)%"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get only the part of the strings between brackets:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Val, "(", -1), ")", 1)
```

and then you can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET(
    '\'EFG\'',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Val, "(", -1), ")", 1)
  )
```

See it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01618/8).